# The use of such a or the article THE

Tags: grammar

While doing some exercises in grammar I came across this question
- Her boss was impressed with...........good job she has done.
I'm confused between "such a" and "the" as answers
My hunch says "the" but I'm not sure.
Please, can someone clear up this confusion?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So according to what you have said the article "the" is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using "the" in this context there is no implied comparison:

```
Her boss was impressed with the good job she had done.
```

When using "such a" there is an implied comparison. The boss is implying that the job is better than expected.

```
Her boss was impressed that she had done such a good job.
```